# Error when fetching a second XML from the web

Tags: android, xml, parsing

im new to android development and im trying to build my first app which looks for a online generated xml file to display information. In the first activity i created a ListView with all the entries from an XML file, as soon as i click on an entry it passes the id and goes to the 2nd activity which should access another XML file with the details. However i keep getting this error when trying to fetch the XML for the details:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl

Any ideas whats wrong? Here is the source for the "details" activity:

```
package en.android.itleaked.com;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.Element;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class showReleases extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.releasedetails);

  getFeed();

 }


 public void getFeed() {
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

  try {
      URL url2 = new URL("http://www.it-leaked.com/app/details.php?id=" + extras.getString("id"));
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbf2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder db2 = dbf2.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc2 = db2.parse(new InputSource(url2.openStream()));
   doc2.getDocumentElement().normalize();
   NodeList nodeList2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("item");
   String relTitle[] = new String[nodeList2.getLength()];
   String relCover[] = new String[nodeList2.getLength()];
   for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node2 = nodeList2.item(i);
    Element fstElmnt2 = (Element) node2;
    NodeList nameList2 = ((Document) fstElmnt2).getElementsByTagName("title");
    Element nameElement2 = (Element) nameList2.item(0);
    nameList2 = ((Node) nameElement2).getChildNodes();
    relTitle[i] = ((Node) nameList2.item(0)).getNodeValue();

    NodeList coverList2 = ((Document) fstElmnt2).getElementsByTagName("cover");
    Element coverElement2 = (Element) coverList2.item(0);
    coverList2 = ((Node) coverElement2).getChildNodes();
    relCover[i] = ((Node) coverList2.item(0)).getNodeValue();
   }
   TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
   txtView.setText(relTitle[0]);

         ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
   Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(relCover[0]);
         imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);


  }
   catch (Exception e) {
    TextView txtView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    txtView2.setText("Error: " + e);
   }

}

  private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
    {
   try
   {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
    return d;
   }catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exc="+e);
    return null;
   }
  }
}
```

Here is the URL for the XML with an attached id so you can see what it looks like:
http://www.it-leaked.com/app/details.php?id=50969

Any ideas whats going on? By the way i added the number 2 to every variable which has something to do with the XML parsing / fetching just to make sure theres no conflict with the other activity, but im still getting the same error..
I hope you can help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Rule of the thumb: always provide us with the most useful information about your error. In your case, you didn't show us your error stack trace. Don't you think it would be easier for us to see where the error occured and on what lines, instead of expecting us to copy & paste, compile and run your code?

Comment: hey, first of all thanks for the reply. im not quite sure what you mean with stack trace. i tried clicking debug but the eclipse console isnt giving me any error message, i got the error message through    catch (Exception e)..thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This question is a little old but I believe the ClassCastException is due to attempting to cast the elements in the nodelist to `android.sax.Element type rather than org.w3c.dom.Element;` check the imports.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your exception (which is java.lang.ClassCastException) the problem is in casting some class to another.

In your code i didn't understand the reason casting Element to Document - Element has getElementsByTagName method which you are using. Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html

It is the root of all evil. Element and Document both implementing Node interface, but Document isn't implements Element - that's why Element can't be cast to Document.

Anyway, expcetion line number can determine the exact error position.